# Prove that the series diverges

Tags: calculus, divergent-series

I am struggling trying to prove that the following series diverges:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{n}}{\sqrt{n}+\sin{n}}
$$
I would be very grateful if anyone could give me some clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is **convergent** by Dirichlet's test: $\sin(n)$ has bounded partial sums and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is decreasing to zero. 
We have
$$ \frac{\sin n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{\sin n}{\sqrt{n}+\sin n} = \frac{\sin^2(n)}{n+\sqrt{n}\sin(n)} $$
and it is enough to show that 
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2019}\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n+\sqrt{n}\sin(n)} $$
is divergent. Due to the equidistribution of $e^{in}$ in $S^1$ we have that for at least $N-O(1)$ integers in the interval $[N,3N]$ the inequality $\sin^2(n)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ holds, so for any $N$ large enough
$$ \sum_{n=N}^{3N}\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n+\sqrt{n}\sin(n)} \geq \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{N-O(1)}{3N+\sqrt{3N}}\geq \frac{1}{7} $$
holds and we are done.

Comment: You can also show that
$\sum_{n\geq 2019}\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n+\sqrt{n}\sin(n)}
$
diverges by noting that
$\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}-\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n+\sqrt{n}\sin(n)}
=\frac{\sqrt{n}\sin^3(n)}{n(n+\sqrt{n}\sin(n))}
$
so that
$\sum_{n\geq 2019}\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n+\sqrt{n}\sin(n)}
=\sum_{n\geq 2019}\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}
-\sum_{n\geq 2019}\frac{\sqrt{n}\sin^3(n)}{n(n+\sqrt{n}\sin(n))}
$
and the first sum diverges
and the second converges.